# Magento rounding problems product prices without tax

Tags: magento

This is not the first time we come across this issue, but it is the first time we cannot solve it with the "known" bug fixes. We have tryed a couple of fixes but none are working. I hope somebody can assist me in the resolution for me and all others facing this annoying problem.

The problem ocurres here in a Magento 1.6.2 install
http://www.trampoline.nl/outdoor/voetbalgoals/aluminium-goal-3-00-x-2-00-incl-net.html

Frontend price: 398,99€ 
Backend price :329.75€

Our tax rate here in The Netherlands is 21%, calculated tax is: 69.25€

So this should be: (69.25€ + 329.75€) = 399.00€

Magento Bug still active in 1.6.2:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=7978

I tryed the following:

- [Magento & Paypal tax rounding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868985/magento-paypal-tax-rounding-issue)
- [Magento tax rounding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529580/magento-tax-rounding-issue)
- http://www.mageext.com/MageExt_FixRound-0.1.0.rar
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/247201/P15/#t361474
- return round($price, 3);
- return round($price, 4);
- return $price;
- etc etc

I hope somebody can help me with this one.

Greetings Gijs
ShopWorks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok fixed it.

First of check if php has the module bcMath installed (--enable-bcmath) if not, compile it.

After that i installed the module:
http://www.mageext.com/MageExt_FixRound-0.1.0.rar

And changed:

```
public function roundPrice($price)
{   
    return round($price,2);
}
```

After that you should see round prices.

To:

```
public function roundPrice($price)
{   
    return round($price);
}
```